# C++: MsiOpenDatabase fails with error 110 0x6e ERROR_OPEN_FAILED only when elevated / admin

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-installer

I am having a problem with calling the function MsiOpenDatabase (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370338(v=vs.85).aspx) from inside a program when I choose to "run as administrator". When I run it under an admin account but without explicitly starting the executable as elevated it all works just fine. This indicates that the path to MSI file etc should be correct.

So, when running elevated the MsiOpenDatabase() I get an error code of 110 (0x6e).
I have tried to call MsiGetLastErrorRecord as explained here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370124(v=vs.85).aspx) but nothing happens when I try to print the code in a message box. It simply doesn't get there.
I do not have Visual studio for debuggning on the target machine, so debugging is a bit of a pain.

Target machine is Windows 7 x64. Application is 32-bit.
But just the pure fact that it works un-elevated but fails when run as an administrator...it feels like there should be some kind of answer to this which can be derived from this fact perhaps?

Thankful for any help!

**EDIT:**
I finally solved it!
Apparently I had to go to the network share where the MSI file is located (which I am trying to call MsiOpenDatabase on) and right cklick on a file there and choose "run as administrator" because then and only then did I get a UAC dialog box asking for credentials (I mean I was able to open Windows Explorer as admin and navigate to the network share without problem so I never thought that it would be what would give me these peoblems). After haing done that I was able to run my application and it did no longer fail on any MsiOpenDatabase call.

But, why must I do this procedure to get access to run file on a network share since I already had access (execute rights) with the same user but when not elevated? How come Windows needs to ask the same user for credentials if it is already running elevated on the very same account that already has access to the network share? Seems strange to me, but I suppose I am missing some crucial part?

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
LPCTSTR szPersist = MSIDBOPEN_READONLY;
MSIHANDLE handleDB;
UINT result = MsiOpenDatabase(strPath, szPersist, &handleDB); // strPath is something like _T("\\server\MSI\Setup.msi");
```

result variable has value 110 when this error occurrs as explained above and keep the part in the update section in mind. I find it strange, but perhaps someone knows UAC better than me and why I have to provide credentials again by going to a file on the netowrk share and choose to run as admin to get it working (since I have already provided credentials as non-admin with the same account earlier at that very same network share location)?

Comment: Do you have this particular database open anywhere else? Unless it's opened with `MSIDBOPEN_READONLY` the file will be locked after the first open.

Comment: @MichaelUrman Nope, it shoudl not be open anywhere else, especially not in any other mode than MSIDBOPEN_READONLY. Also I have now tried on other machines and there it works just fine even when elevated. Seems like it must be something in the environment. The failing environment is a pretty clean VMWare machine. I'm thinking Windows Updates may be good to install but Windows Update is so slow (searching now...)

Comment: Please post a sample of your code.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Please see the update section and sample code.

Comment: Do you close your handles? Also you should be using PMSIHANDLE not MSIHANDLE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204770(v=vs.85).aspx#close_handle

Answer (score 0):

This is standard UAC behavior since Windows Vista and is not related to MSI at all.  Do a google search for "uac network drives".

You should be closing your MSI handles though as I commented above.  Use PMSIHANDLE instead of MSIHANDLE.

Comment: I have checked and I do close the handles manually, and that should make it ok to use MSIHANDLE.

But if that is standard UAC behavior it is strange that this only happens to me.